# How can we create case class object from json in scala + play framework 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Hi I have a case class .

```
case class User(
  name: Name,
  gender: String ,age:string}
```

This is a sample case class in some cases my json is incomplete like

```
{"name":"sagar","gendar":"male"}
```

Now when I am trying to convert this json to case class using following code

```
  import sjson.json._
val js = JsValue.fromString(json);
   val userObj = fromjson[User](js)
```

It's giving me error .
Is there any way we can create case class objects from incomplete JSON.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your case class to:

```
case class User(name: Name,gender: String ,age:Option[String])
```

If age won't always be there, you need to declare it as optional.

In addition, if age is actually an `int` in the json when specified like this:

```
{"name":"sagar","gendar":"male", "age":25}
```

Then the case class will have to be defined as:

```
case class User(name: Name,gender: String ,age:Option[Int])
```